# Syncing of Calendar with iCloud lose the CalendarIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, calendar, icloud

I am developing a Calendar App. In which calendars can be create by user and also need the `iCloud` Syncing feature so that user can get the same calendars on his/her other device. Now according to Apple Document:

`A full sync with the calendar will lose this identifier. You should have a plan for dealing with a calendar whose identifier is no longer fetchable by caching its other properties.`

`CalendarIdentifier` property of `EKCalendar` is not reliable. And using other properties we can not differentiate the calendar as well that it is made by iOS Native Calendar App or My Calendar App. So I am stuck here and trying to find any reliable solution. But not able to find till now so please help me for this to get the solution. I will be thankful to you.